# Directx Window keeps Crashing

Tags: directx

My problem with this code is that when I run it in visual C++ A window pops up
but then it just crashes. It is not responding and I cannot click exit. I have to pull up the
task manager to get rid of the window. I am new to windows programming and direct X.
Below I will post were I think the problem is.

```
#include <d3d9.h>

#include <time.h>

#define APPTITLE "Direct3D_Windowed"

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE);
int Game_Init(HWND);
void GAME_RUN(HWND);
void GAME_END(HWND);

LPDIRECT3D9 d3d = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev = NULL;

// Over here, after GAME_END() is called, I tried separating the POSTQUITMESSAGE But I
  I just got an error.

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     switch(msg )
     {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        GAME_END(hWnd);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
}

return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
WNDCLASSEX wc;
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WinProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = NULL;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = APPTITLE;
wc.hIconSm = NULL;

return RegisterClassEx(&wc);
}

// I got this code from a book that I am reading and realized that WinProc is not being
  called in this function. Is this the potential problem? Were would I put the WinProc
  function call if it is supposed to be here in WinMain

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
MSG msg = {0};
MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
HWND hWnd;

hWnd = CreateWindow(
    APPTITLE,
    APPTITLE,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    500,
    400,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

if(!hWnd)
    return FALSE;

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

if(!Game_Init(hWnd))
    return 0;

int done = 0;

while(!done)
{
    if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
    {

        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "Recieve WM_QUIT message", "WinMain", MB_OK);
            done = 1;
        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    else
        GAME_RUN(hWnd);

}

return msg.wParam;
 }

 int Game_Init(HWND hWnd)
{
MessageBox(hWnd, "Program is about to start", "Game_Init", MB_OK);

d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
if(d3d == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(hWnd, "Error initializing Direct3D", "Error", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;

d3d->CreateDevice(
    D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
    D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
    hWnd,
    D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
    &d3dpp,
    &d3ddev);

if(d3ddev == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(hWnd, "Error creating Direct device", "Error", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

srand(time(NULL));

return 1;
}

void GAME_RUN(HWND hWnd)
{
if(d3ddev == NULL)
    return;

d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), 1.0f, 0);
if(d3ddev->BeginScene())
{
    d3ddev->EndScene();
}

d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

void GAME_END(HWND hWnd)
{
MessageBox(hWnd, "Program is about to end", "Game End", MB_OK);

if(d3ddev != NULL)
    d3ddev->Release();

if(d3d != NULL)
    d3d->Release();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this?

```
if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
```

In your while-loop.
Perhaps change that to, say:

```
if(true)
```

Reason: you want your application to pass on all messages, not just the ones that cause it to quit. Say for instance when windows wants your application to draw itself. Basically, your current code doenst allow your application to do *anything* except quitting.

If you want to do something special when the application quits, add another `case WM_QUIT:` after the already existing `case WM_DESTROY:` in `WinProc()`.

The current location for `GAME_RUN(hWnd);` will not work out for you.
You want to either put that in a seperate thread (easiest, and highest performance). Or you want to use some timers, and handle it with `case WM_TIMER:` after your `case WM_DESTROY:`. Or alternatively make up your own user defined message.